What causes difference in how title is displayed for tabs with and without "/index" in their names in React Native Expo Navigation?
Just started learning react native, specifically the tab navigation, and went through the following tutorial on the topic.
What I can't figure out is some inconsistent behaviour of how the tabs titles are displayed.
E.g. consider the following file structure, in which both tab_1 and tab_2 dirs have the same file structure and the same immediate parent i.e. (tabs) dir:
app
│ _layout.tsx
│ (tabs)
│   │ _layout.tsx
│   │ _index.tsx
│   │ tab_1
│   │   │ index.tsx
│   │ tab_2
│       │ index.tsx

Here is the code of app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx:
const TabsLayout = () => {
    return (
        <Tabs>
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="index"
                options={{
                    headerTitle: "Home Tab",
                    title: "Home Tab Title"
                }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="tab_1"
                options={{
                    headerTitle: "Tab 1",
                    title: "Tab 1 Title"
                }}
            />

            <Tabs.Screen
                name="tab_2/index"
                options={{
                    headerTitle: "Tab 2",
                    title: "Tab 2 Title"
                }} 
                />
        </Tabs>
    )
} 

Notice that name for the tab_1 tab is just "tab_1", but the name for the tab_2 tab is "tab_2/index" (i.e. not just "tab_2" unlike with its tab_1 counterpart). With such setup, the tab_2 title is correctly displayed i.e. "Tab 2 Title".

However, once I change the tab_2 name to just "tab_2", the name changes to "tab_2/index", which is the path to the index.tsx in tab_2 dir.

Interestingly enough, if I change the tab_1 name to "tab_1/index, the tab_1 title changes to "tab_1", and not "tab_1/index", unlike its tab_2 counterpart.

The author of the article specifically mentions that such name difference for tab_1 and tab_2 has to take place:
Modify app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx to change the name for the tab from tab_1/index to tab_1
but doesn't indicate the reason for it.
Since I've asked him, but hasn't gotten a reply, wondering if anyone knows

the reason for such different behaviour of the tabs, despite the same structure?
if there is a way to make them work identical (i.e. both tabs names have the same pattern e.g. either "tab_1" & "tab_2" or "tab_1/index" & "tab_2/index" and the titles show properly for both of them)?

Thank you
